# Auto create/update Tables using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, autocreate

i have an ***Spring + Hibernate*** based application where the most properties are setted using ***annotations***.

My ***AppConfig class*** looks like:

```
//package declarations and imports 

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.package.subpackage.*" })
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fur");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        driverManagerDataSource.setConnectionProperties(prop);
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    //other methods...

}
```

The **problem** I have is that the tables associated with my Java classes are ***not auto-created in my database***.

I dont add examples of my class beacause I think its in the configuration the issue, but please let me know if is needed.

Comment: You are setting the properties containing `hibernate.hmb2ddl.auto` on the data source, which doesn't know anything about ORM layer such as Hibernate. You should pass these properties to `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder` bean or such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the properties containing `hibernate.hmb2ddl.auto` on the data source, which doesn't know anything about ORM layer such as Hibernate. You should pass these properties to [`LocalSessionFactoryBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.html) bean or such.

You could use similar configuration to set-up Hibernate with the required properties:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    // Data source, transaction manager, ... bean definitions omitted

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
        sfb.scanPackages("com.example.app.model");
        // Hibernate/JPA properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        sfb.addProperties(properties);
        return sfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactoryBuilder().buildSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

Comment: excelent, with a similar approach i just make it work, using your comment. Thanks so much for your help!